# DataGridTemplateColumn not centering correctly

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am trying to create a CheckBox which only requires one click to select it (as opposed to the usual two - one to activate it, another to select) and that is working, but now the column border is incorrect:

[image: Comes out looking like this]

Here is the XAML I am using:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="To OC">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Export, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

What am I missing here to get the column border in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DataGridCheckBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Represents a DataGrid column that hosts CheckBox controls in its cells.

Example:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="To OC"
                        Width="SizeToHeader"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=Export, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
```

In this case the `CheckBox` stands in the middle of the DataGridCell. In addition, the standard `CheckBox` implies that it has *Content*, but in the case of the `DataGrid` no Content. Perhaps this explains the crooked alignment, to fix it can be also using the `Margin`.

Comment: I was using DataGridCheckBoxColumn, but then it requires 2 mouse clicks to check the box.  Adding a small right Margin did the trick (albeit hacky).